# Math.sin подскажите где ошибка, браузер просто зависает

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

 var a,b,c,d;

 a = window.prompt( "Введите Х начальное", "10");
 b = window.prompt( "Введите шаг h ", "2" );

 c = parseInt ( a ) ; 
 d = parseInt( b );

  num=1;
 while (num <= c) {
      document.write(num + "<BR>");
     num = Math.sin (num+d) + Math.cos (num+d)
   }

</SCRIPT>
 </HEAD> 
 <BODY>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: @Максим-t7, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: в общем у вас очевидно условие выхода не происходит, во - при c==2 не выйдет никогда, потому-что http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2Bcos%28x%29

Comment: Контент страницы не рендерится во время пробега скриптов. Попробуйте разбить вычисления на куски по, скажем, 100 строк, и откладывать вычисление следующего куска через таймаут.

Comment: ну я пробовал вводить а = 0,1, b = 0,2.. все равно ниче не происходит(

Comment: у вас там parseint при 0.1 и 0.2 c=0, а num=1 , т.о (1<=0) - сразу выходим.

Comment: вот ваш код в "безопасном" исполнении http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/42AL2/

Comment: @eicto вообще то максимальное значение `sin(x)+cos(x)=sqrt(2)=~1.414`

Comment: @Barmaley и разве это противоречит

    six(x)+cos(x)<1.5 

?

Answer (score 1):

```
| sin + cos | <= sqrt(2) и выход из цикла не происходит, т.к. a вводится либо по умолчанию = 2, что удовлетворяет условию работы цикла, либо еще больше, что тем более удовлетворяет выполнению оператора повтора. А сделать вы видимо хотели вот это:
```